# How to add some of my /home memory to /(root)

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, gparted, root

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 as dual boot along with windows 7.
I got a message that my root directory is almost full.
Here is the screenshot -
[gparted screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2eSo.png)

I want to resize my home directory to 80GB and rest I want to add to root.
When i click on resize i get a message saying - 
 "Minimum size: 161765 MiB      Maximum size: 161765 MiB" 
[resize window screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A8Mu.png)

and I am unable to resize it.
Can anybody guide me through this.
This is my first post. I am sorry for any mistakes. Please tell me if you need any other information.

Comment: Memory comes in chips on memory modules. /home does not use memory, it uses disk space.

Comment: can you share some article on how to resize with LiveUSB please

Comment: @dot0matrix It will be identical to your current method, just make sure to boot to the LiveUSB.

Comment: @dot0matrix Do you know how to use a LiveUSB?

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to shrink down another partition that you don’t need as much of. Currently, your entire drive is taken up by partitions. Select the partition that you want to shrink and use the same resize tool to make it smaller.

Edit: Make sure to use a LiveUSB.

Comment: i want to shrink my home and add the memory to the root. is it possible?

Comment: In your case, shrink a partition by 80gb. You will want to double check, but I think that you will want to shrink /dev/sda4

Comment: If you want to go with home, it looks like you have enough free space to remove 80gb. Make sure to double check that you are not destroying anything important, but I think it can be done.

Comment: yes but iam unable to resize home. do i have to unmount it or something?

Comment: A live USB could help.

Comment: You must boot from a LiveUSB because you can't edit a partition you booted from.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: There's no reason to reduce /home to 80G, as that much room is not required to expand /.

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- **resize** /dev/sda8 by dragging the right side of the partition to the left by 20G
- **move** /dev/sda8 partition all the way right
- **resize** /dev/sda7 by dragging the right side of the partition all the way right
- click the Apply icon